# Should I use \big | or \vert?

Tags: typography

I want to type `f(x)` is a factor of `g(x)`. I tried `f(x) \big| g(x)` and `f(x)  \vert | g(x)` Should I use \big | or  \vert?

Comment: None  of them.  You should use `f(x)\mid g(x)`  for spacing (and semantic) reasons. It is not a delimiter, but a relation symbol.

Comment: An alternative might be `\bigm|`, but `\mid` is better.

Comment: @egreg Why is `\mid` better in that situation? I would've used `\bigm|` for that particular situation.